# android - importing custom library

Tags: android

I developed a library that contains some Activities but when I try to show an activity android throws an exception on retrieving library resource.

```
// code extract from activity.onCreate in library
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.library_resource, null).
```

If I add this library by `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars...` it doesn't work but adding the library by Android project by `Project Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add...` it works fine.

Could anyone tell me why importing the jar it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use assets/resources in the library project that you can add as a library project to your project.While using jar you can't add such assets/jars in there.So in your case when you add as library project its working because the resource is imported from library project to main project.While using jar this is not happening.So you are getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

In Android library projects, the resources are bundled separately from the jar.  It will let you compile because it generates the R file, but the actual resources won't be present.

Comment: how to fix that? ... Do I have to install original library on phone? Or do I need to copy library to app path too? Or how can I link it to my application?